# Is there a better way to write the following?

Tags: php, syntax

I got confronted with this "problem" several times already, I fix it the same way but I feel dirty just by thinking how I solved it.

Let's say I work with Drupal 8 and that I need to modify several select form's default value, "-Any-" by "Select...".

This is how I proceed each time :

```
    if(isset($form['field_children_charge_value'])) {
      $form['field_children_charge_value']['#options']['All'] = t('Select...');
    }
    if(isset($form['field_evolution_target_id'])) {
      $form['field_evolution_target_id']['#options']['All'] = t('Select...');

    }
    // And so on
```

I feel bad writing like this, but, for my defense, I didn't have a lot of of PHP theory while learning, I directly got the practical courses.

an `elseif` expression would only work once since the first condition will match the pre requisite, and it won't bother checking if some other condition would work too.

I also got the problem once with javascript, and I did the same thing.

So, is there a better syntax, and if yes, what is it?

Comment: are you doing the same thing everytime?

Comment: Yes, and that's what bothers me

Comment: you could use id's in an array & use this in foreach loop

Comment: ...I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been years since I coded in php, but this seems like a general "issue".
You can save all the fields in an **array**, and then use a **for-each** loop to execute the operation on each of them:

```
$fields = ["field1", "field2", "..."];

foreach($fields as $field) {
  if(isset($form[$field])) {
    $form[$field]['#options']['All'] = t('Select...');
  }
}
```